# Calling messages.properties dynamically with controller model variable and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, properties-file

I have my **messages.properties** like this:

```
tablas.menu.paises=Pa\u00EDses
tablas.menu.regiones=Regiones
tablas.menu.anhos=A\u00F1os
tablas.menu.universidades=Universidades
tablas.menu.usuarios=Usuarios
```

In the **.html** I have a menu showing each item with th:each:

```
<li class="nav-item" th:each="menu : ${menus}">
  <a th:text="#{tablas.menu.${menu.nombre}}"></a>
</li>
```

For each "menu in ${menus}", menu.nombre has the values paises, regiones, anhos...
But thymeleaf doesn't recognise the model variable inside the #{}, and this it is giving me in the view the error when it doesn't find the message:

```
??tablas.menu.${menu.nombre}_es_ES??
```

Configuration is ok, if I change the call for #{tablas.menu.regiones} I get 'regiones' and so.
Is there any way to call a message from messages.properties dynamically using a model variable like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try the Thymeleaf [preprocessor](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#preprocessing). So, for example: `_${menu.nombre}_`.

Comment: Damn thank you so much, I didn't know that feature and it works. th:text="#{tablas.menu.__${menu.nombre}__}" is working perfect.

Comment: And thank you for correcting my typo - _double_ underscores are needed, not singles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`#messages` utility object](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#messages-1) for this:

```
<a th:text="${#messages.msg('tablas.menu.' + menu.nombre)}" />
```

Or you can create the string using [literal substitution](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions):

```
<a th:text="#{|tablas.menu.${menu.nombre}|}" />
```

I would recommend using preprocessing only as a last resort, as bad values can cause runtime errors. (Although they do work for this.)